# In Visual Studio 2013, can the button be hard coded to play a video from a known path?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have created a simple media player using VB in Visual Studio 2013. My requirement is: just by pressing a button, I need to play the video file available at a fixed path (using the `OpenFileDialog` I have fixed the path). E.g. pressing a button named 'A' should play a file from 'C:/Playlists'

How can this be done? I can share my current code if needed. I'm new to VB.

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    With OpenFileDialog1
        .Filter = "MPEG-4|*.mp4"
        .ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Text = .FileName
    End With
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = (OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop()
End Sub

Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = TrackBar1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.volume = 20
End Sub

End Class
```

I need buttons named A,B,C etc like play, pause which i already have. On pressing button A should play 'file_A.mp3' from 'C:\Playlist'

Comment: When asking for help on specific programming questions, *always* share your code.  There are multiple ways to do almost everything, and seeing what you're working with will help us help you.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with?  Detecting the button click?  Using a different path depending on which button was clicked?  Showing the dialog?  Setting the initial folder of the dialog?  Getting the selected file path from the dialog?  Playing the video?  You aren't being very clear.

Comment: Somewhat Pedantic Side note: on Windows, paths use backslashes (`\ `) not forward slashes (`/`)

Answer (score 0):

```
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\Playlist\file_A.mp3"
AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play()
```

Comment: @RajeevHV - Mark it as the answer :)